# Android Studio: Integrating Butterknife?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, butterknife

I am trying to implement [Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) into my android studio project.

However when I do so I get an error on `@InjectView` "cannot resolve symbol InjectView".

Have I not implemented Butterknife sucsessfully?

Activity code:

```
package com.example.rodf.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.tvHelloWorld) TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }
}
```

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHelloWorld"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rodf.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    //adding the butter knife library
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you synced your gradle file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your code is good,

1. Try to sync your gradle by click [image]
2. Try to go `File` -- `invalidate Caches` and restart your Android studio.

Also, don't forget put `ButterKnife.inject(this);` in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 20):

Note that in the latest versions of the ButterKnife library, the `@InjectView()` annotation is no longer used.

In stead `@Bind(R.id.tvHelloWorld)` and `ButterKnife.bind(this);` are used.

Reference: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Answer (score 11):

So ButterKnife just got updated with version `8.5.1`

To use that,

Add below line inside project-level `build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.5.1'
```

Add below lines inside app-level `build.gradle`:

```
// Field and method binding for Android views
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

Apply butterknife plugin as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

A little change in syntax to previous ButterKnife version is that, now you have to use `R2` instead of `R` while using ButterKnfe annotations.

To be specific:

Instead of writing

```
@BindView(R.id.textView)
TextView mTextView;
```

We will be writing

```
@BindView(R2.id.textView)
TextView mTextView;
```

and then simply build the project.

Comment: This is a huge change.  It's unfortunate that it's not documented or reflected at http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife, and the documentation at https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife only partially reflects the change -- the early code samples on the page use R, and the later ones use R2.  It's also unfortunate that you can upgrade to 8.5.1, not change any of your R references to R2, and it still compiles and runs -- what kind of mysterious bugs have I got now?  This is a mess.

Comment: Life saver, I think. I was trying to debug for a half an hour, and turns out, the version code is the only cause of this. Facepalm

Answer (score 9):

Set up manual configuration for ButterKnife from [this link](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-idea.html)

File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings

Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Check Enable annotation processing

Comment: Before year this answer was perfect, but now Android studio does not have those settings

Comment: Yes it does, but the location changed: `File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler* -> Annotations Processors* -> Enable annotation processing`

Note that the ones with `*` are under a sub menu that you manually have to show. 

Also you can simply search on the Search field for: "Enable annotation" and it will show up.

Answer (score 2):

Move the *TextView tv1* declaration inside your class.
Also call the *ButterKnife.inject(this);* method.

```
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.tvHelloWorld) TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the answer's but nothing is working for me because in the library they changed something. Insteded of @InjectView try @Bind. It will work fine

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions of the ButterKnife library(8.5.1), the `@InjectView()` annotation is not used.

You can use `@BindView(Component)` instead of @InjectView(Component) and instead of using `Butterknife.inject(this)` use  `ButterKnife.bind(this)`