# Difference between bind and injectView in butterknife

Tags: android, butterknife

I am using butterknife library. I don't know much about how to use it. I found injectView and bind doing the same thing but I am not really sure. Can anyone explain the difference between these two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Can anyone explain the difference between these two ?

`@InjectView` was changed to `@Bind` .

> Annotate fields with @Bind and a view ID for Butter Knife to find and
>   automatically cast the corresponding view in your layout.

```
class YourActivity extends Activity {
  @Bind(R.id.TvTitle) TextView title;
```

Please check below links. Hope this helps .

1. **[JakeWharton Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)**
2. **[The import butterknife.InjectView cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531475/the-import-butterknife-injectview-cannot-be-resolved)**
3. **[Introduction Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)**

**GRADLE**

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1' //8.4.0
```

> https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/f65dc849d80f6761d1b4a475626c568b2de883d9/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: One more thing. I am using android studio. Here its only showing @InjectView but not Bind.

Comment: `@Bind(R.id.TvTitle) and ButterKnife.bind(this);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138859/android-studio-integrating-butterknife

Comment: Oops! I was using version 5.x.x.

Answer (score 7):

If I'm not mistaken, they have the same function. There was a change in naming convention starting version 7 of butterknife, `injectView` was changed to `bind`.

Check the [changelog](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-700-2015-06-27), also check [this issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/331).

Check this link:
[How to use butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Answer (score 0):

As of Version 8.0.0 @Bind becomes @BindView and @BindViews

Check the [butterknife changelog](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-700-2015-06-27) for further information!