# Unresolved Reference: "ButterKnife"

Tags: android, butterknife

I am getting the above compiler error, but I can't fix it no matter what I do.

#### MyActivity

```
import butterknife.ButterKnife // Unresolved Reference: ButterKnife
import butterknife.BindView // Unresolved Reference: BindView

class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    @BindView(R.id.textView)
    lateinit var mTextView: TextView

    // ...

}
```

#### build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

#### build.gradle (Module)

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
}
```

## What I've tried so far...

1. Scoured the internet for solutions, including [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138859/android-studio-integrating-butterknife)
2. Deleted the .idea folder & restart
3. Invalidate cache & restart
4. Clean Project
5. Gradle Sync
6. Cry

Comment: It might be case sensitive, so try "butterknife" instead of "Butterknife".

Comment: "ButterKnife" is correct. In fact, when I add a . (dot) after butterknife, nothing comes up as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'` instead of annotationProcessor. This dependency contains your missing package, so it should be `implementation` or `api` if you want to use it in your code.

In this case annotationProcessor is not good for you, because it generally used for code generators, like `butterknife-compiler`.

Comment: wow! just like that it worked! the only reason i was using "annotationProcessor" in the first place was because the compiler was giving me a warning "Add annotation processor to processor path using annotationProcessor instead of implementation" Looks like the compiler was stupid af (which is not usually the case)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the jcenter() dependency in the build.gradle file of your project (not app) ?

```
   allprojects {
     repositories {
      ...
      jcenter()
      }
   }
```

Comment: Good catch, but unfortunately it's already in place. I've updated my post to reflect your suggestion.